# I want to show the Divider after the text end. It will end on one line, second line or third line

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I want to show the Divider when the text will end. It will close on the 1st line, 2nd line or 3rd line. After that the Divider will show the remaning space.
I want to achieve the above image UI.

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      flex: 1 /*or any integer value above 0 (optional)*/,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            list[index].event!.name!.length > 40 ? Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /1.1,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: Text(
                list[index].event!.name!,
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: white,
                ),
              ),
            ) :
              Expanded(
                flex: 0 /*or any integer value above 0 (optional)*/,
                child: Text( list[index].event!.name!,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: white,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                )),
            Expanded(child:Divider(color: appTextColor.withOpacity(0.2)))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

How can I achieve this behavior (the dashes should be the divider):

Short Text ---------------

Loooooooooooooong Text ---

Tooooooooooooooooooo
Long Text -----------------  // <- Divider should be here then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve the needed result.

`main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_flutter/divider_text.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Text Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 32);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Text Test'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const DividerText(
            'Title',
            style: textStyle,
            indent: 4.0,
            endIndent: 4.0,
            dividerThickness: 2.0,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 64.0),
          DividerText(
            'Title' * 100,
            style: textStyle,
            indent: 4.0,
            endIndent: 4.0,
            dividerThickness: 2.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`divider_text.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DividerText extends StatelessWidget {
  const DividerText(this.text, {
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.style,
    this.indent,
    this.endIndent,
    this.dividerThickness,
    this.dividerColor,
  });

  final double? width;
  final String text;
  final TextStyle? style;
  final double? indent;
  final double? endIndent;
  final double? dividerThickness;
  final Color? dividerColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenWidth = width ?? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var textInfo = (TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style),
      textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    )..layout(maxWidth: screenWidth)).computeLineMetrics().last;
    var lastWidth = textInfo.width % screenWidth;
    var dividerWidth = screenWidth - lastWidth;
    return SizedBox(
      width: screenWidth,
      height: textInfo.height * (textInfo.lineNumber + 1),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: dividerWidth,
              child: Divider(
                height: textInfo.height,
                thickness: dividerThickness ?? 1.0,
                indent: indent,
                endIndent: endIndent,
                color: dividerColor ?? style?.color ?? DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(text, style: style),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the screenshot:
[image: The Result]

Comment: Than you so much Litva Nick